# Kiosk Mode in Android L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

My Activity Enters Kiosk Mode in Android L via :

```
protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        try {
            KioskActivity.this.startLockTask();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

And exits on Click of button :

```
 KioskActivity.this.stopLockTask();
```

Now the issue is when in Kiosk mode dialog apper it comes with status bar below since i hv editext in kiosk mode 
How to get rid of this ?

Comment: quick note - you do not need `KioskActivity.this.` as you are in scope of `KioskActivity` already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue, when kiosk mode enter the softkeyboard comes with status bar since while leaving the kiosk mode kill process via :

```
android.os.process.killprocess(android.os.process.mypid())
```

And start actvity with setflag as `New_TASK`

Comment: you means Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK?